# How to use “—privileged” flag on docker container in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I tried to use the “—privileged” flag on my container but it didn't work.
Is there any possibility to use the “—privileged” flag at docker container in Bluemix?

Answer (score 5):

Privileged mode is not supported for security reasons, because IBM Containers run on a shared infrastructure and evidently we can't provide root access to the users. If you need something like that, you should try the Virtual Machines Bluemix Service to have full access to the machine.

Answer (score 1):

The `--privileged` flag is not supported in the IBM Containers.
The supported flags for `cf ic run` are the following:

```
--name, -it, -m, --memory, -e, --env, -p, -publish, -v, --volume, --link
```

This is documented the link below:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_native-docker.html